# .Net app - launching url - need to prevent local storage being used

Tags: javascript, html, .net, local-storage

does anybody know how to launch a url from within a HTML webpage that will prevent the browser from reading the local storage? My .Net app generates the URL which it passes to the HTML web page.

Thanks

tried to open in iframe and use jaavscript to clear local storage for that domain but it wouldn't run (which I kind of expected)